# Android google maps "NoClassDefFound"

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-widget

i already put          `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />` in the
application tag.

when im trying to move to this activity i got crash.

this is my java file:

**

```
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MyMap extends MapActivity {   

    @Override  
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.mapactivity);  
    }  

    @Override  
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {  
        return false;  
    }  
}
```

and this is my xml file: (at my_api_key i got my own key that i got from google)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapview1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="my_api_key" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

and when i go to the editor in eclipse i see:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUUHb.jpg

thanks.

the full stack trace:
03-08 07:06:10.554: E/AndroidRuntime(18227): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Fproj.dnlgby.MyMap
03-08 07:06:10.554: E/AndroidRuntime(18227):    at Fproj.dnlgby.MenuActivity.onClick(MenuActivity.java:60)
03-08 07:06:10.554: E/AndroidRuntime(18227):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2496)
03-08 07:06:10.554: E/AndroidRuntime(18227):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9120)
03-08 07:06:10.554: E/AndroidRuntime(18227):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-08 07:06:10.554: E/AndroidRuntime(18227):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-08 07:06:10.554: E/AndroidRuntime(18227):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-08 07:06:10.554: E/AndroidRuntime(18227):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3859)
03-08 07:06:10.554: E/AndroidRuntime(18227):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-08 07:06:10.554: E/AndroidRuntime(18227):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-08 07:06:10.554: E/AndroidRuntime(18227):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:840)
03-08 07:06:10.554: E/AndroidRuntime(18227):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:598)
03-08 07:06:10.554: E/AndroidRuntime(18227):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-08 07:06:10.554: E/AndroidRuntime(18227): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation
03-08 07:06:10.554: E/AndroidRuntime(18227):    at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(Native Method)
03-08 07:06:10.554: E/AndroidRuntime(18227):    at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:207)
03-08 07:06:10.554: E/AndroidRuntime(18227):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:200)
03-08 07:06:10.554: E/AndroidRuntime(18227):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
03-08 07:06:10.554: E/AndroidRuntime(18227):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
03-08 07:06:10.554: E/AndroidRuntime(18227):    ... 12 more

Comment: Can you post the actual stack trace? When you say Move the class what do you mean? The img you link to, that basically means that your style isn't in Theme. Use the dropdown in the upper right corner to select the theme of the activity that you would like this to run in with mapViewStyle defined.

Comment: posted the full stack trace. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Is this running on a device or the emulator?  If it's on the emulator is the emulator set to provide Google APIs?

Comment: its running on my device (motorola razer)

Comment: fixed. the problem was that i included the google maps lib on my build path and use google api.

Comment: what does that mean @DanielGabay.Could you please elaborate.What have you done to successfully display map in your App.I have the same error cumin up in my device not emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error by checking "Copy projects into workspace" while importing the Google Play Services lib.
More info here: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Comment: yeah I think this question is no longer valid since it is for Google Maps Api V1. V2 works as you said but in the past there was no alternative and this error plagued people for a while. The perceived behavior is that the class for MapActivity (v1 SDK only) would fail some initialization and then fail to load as a class entirely. Then this would crash your app randomly with a very cryptic stack error.